# 80’s kids film about two kids who rent a film and get sucked into the TV

Tags: story-identification, movie, soft-sci-fi

This has been bugging me for such a long time. It’s a film about two kids who go to a video store, and this particular video stands out as it has a silver cover.

When they play it, they are sucked into the the TV and held prisoner by some weird typical 80’s sci-fi villain.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TrappedInTVLand

Answer (score 3):

*Andy Colby's Incredible Adventure* (1988) most likely.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094655):

> Andy Colby is doomed to another typical day of babysitting. But this day is anything but typical when Andy's little sister is pulled through the TV and Andy is sent on an incredibly awesome adventure to save her!

The trailer below (in Spanish) opens with Andy trying to reach a VHS standing out because of its silver cover ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fczaj.png)). The rest looks as 80s as it gets. If you speak Spanish, the movie is available on Youtube, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBbDVpndi0E).

---

Found with the Google query `movie kids rent a film and get sucked into the TV` which brought up [this solved Yahoo! Answers thread](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110125073422AAHt3kl).